# Responsive Photoswipe

Tags: javascript, html, photoswipe

Photoswipe is responsive. But i can't get mine to look good in mobile.

First image is my version second from the demo.
I Copied the gallery code from demo.
This is link to my project: http://madeleinepersson.net/Photoswipe

```html
             <div id="gallery" class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="pswp__bg"></div>

        <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">

          <div class="pswp__container">
   <div class="pswp__item"></div>
   <div class="pswp__item"></div>
   <div class="pswp__item"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">

            <div class="pswp__top-bar">

    <div class="pswp__counter"></div>

    <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>

    <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button>

    <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>

    <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>

    <div class="pswp__preloader">
     <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
       <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
         <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
            </div>


   <!-- <div class="pswp__loading-indicator"><div class="pswp__loading-indicator__line"></div></div> -->

            <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
             <div class="pswp__share-tooltip">
     <!-- <a href="#" class="pswp__share--facebook"></a>
     <a href="#" class="pswp__share--twitter"></a>
     <a href="#" class="pswp__share--pinterest"></a>
     <a href="#" download class="pswp__share--download"></a> -->
             </div>
         </div>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)"></button>
            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)"></button>
            <div class="pswp__caption">
              <div class="pswp__caption__center">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

[image: This is my version]

[image: This is from the demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to PhotoSwipe. Your sample page is not a valid HTML document, there is no doctype, no html, head or body element. You need to fix that first.

You should add the [viewport meta element](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#viewport-meta) to your page. Using the one line of code below, the viewport's width is set to the device width, not to some larger value used by mobile browsers to make websites look „ok“ that are not prepared for mobile, like yours right now. Add this to your `head` element and your page should look like the demo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: thanks, it's just on a testpage now so i didn't think of it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also see that your photos are in landscape mode, so the image will appear as such when viewed in portrait mode on mobile device. You can combine portrait orientation images to fill whole frame on site.